# Which output variables from the vertex shader will be interpolated?

Tags: opengl, shader, render, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I noticed that `out vec4 vertexColor` variable in the vertex shader will be interpolated when entering the fragment shader `in vec4 vertexColor`. My question is, will all variables with the "out" modifier be interpolated or only a certain type?

Comment: Like texture coordinates they are all hyperbolically interpolated by the rasterizer.

Answer (score 3):

All user-defined [inputs to the fragment shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Inputs) are interpolated. *How* they are interpolated is a matter of the [`layout` interpolation qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers). By default, `in` will use `smooth`, but you can specify `noperspective` (interpolation in screen space with no perspective correction) or `flat`. The later performs "interpolation" by giving all fragments the value of the variable assigned to the [provoking vertex of the primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Provoking_Vertex). Integral types being input by the FS must use `flat`, but the default is still `smooth`, so you will get a compile error if you don't explicitly specify `flat` for them.

Note that while you asked about vertex shader outputs, the answer is about *fragment* shader *inputs*. There's a reason for that.

First, there are multiple shader stages that can exist before the fragment shader. The values given to the FS come from the last active [vertex processing shader stage](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Processing): geometry shader, tessellation evaluation shader, or vertex shader. Mesh shaders (a relatively recent extension) change what vertex processing stages exist, but the last one is still the one that feeds the fragment shader.

So just talking about the "vertex shader" would be incomplete.

Second, interpolation qualifiers on vertex processing stage outputs are *ignored*. The only ones that matter are those on the fragment shader *inputs*. This is a relatively recent change, in terms of GLSL version numbers. Before GLSL 4.30, the final vertex processing stage outputs needed to have the same qualifiers as the corresponding fragment shader inputs. Since 4.30, they don't but the vertex output qualifiers are just ignored; only the fragment shader input qualifiers matter.

Answer (score 0):

See [Type Qualifier (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)). Interpolation of floating point type outputs depends on the interpolation qualifier, which are `flat`, `noperspective` or `smooth`. The default is `smooth`. Outputs of an integral type must be qualified with the qualifier `flat` (otherwise you get an error) and are not interpolated.

Comment: "*Outputs of integral type are not interpolated*" It would be more accurate to say that if you output an integral type without the `flat` qualifier, you get a compile error.

Comment: What about mat2-4? Are they also interpolated by default?

Comment: @tomeadom Yes. `mat2`, `mat3`, `mat4` are floating point types. The components of the matrices are interpolated depending on the interpolation qualifier.